# unable to import created vector drawable

Tags: android, svg, vector

I had a image of formulas which i converted it to svg format and then to vector drawable format.When i imported it to the project it shows the error in the xml layout

here is the vector drawable

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="290"
android:viewportHeight="242"
android:width="362.5dp"
android:height="302.5dp"></vector>
```

[here is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCTrB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of you are not giving path in vector..

[try this link for converting svg into vector](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)